# Импорт классов в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

У менять есть файл `test.ts`

В нем импортируется классы из файлов `jsfile` и `tsfile`

```
jsfile.js:

class MyClass {
    age
    myfunc(){
        console.log("someTestFunction = " + this.age)
    }
}
module.exports = {MyClass}


tsfile.ts:
export class MyClass2 {
    age:number
    myfunc():void{
        console.log("someTestFunction = " + this.age)
    }
}

test.ts:

import {MyClass} from "./jsfile"
import {MyClass2} from "./tsfile"

const obj1:MyClass = new MyClass()

const  obj2:MyClass2 = new MyClass2()

console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj2)
```

В выводе получаю следующий результат:

```
MyClass { age: undefined }
MyClass2 {}
```

Почему в классе, который был импортирован из `js` файла, переменная `age` есть, а в классе из `ts` ее вообще нет? почему в обоих классах нет метода?

Comment: 1. Особенности компиляции ts в js. 2. Особенность `console.log` - метод будет в прототипе (\_\_proto\_\_).

Answer (score 0):

### Пример

- [с флагом useDefineForClassFields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XTAcwKYC50DsBPJAXySWAHt8IAXdaAXmnywHc4LqJKQsA6EJQwAKMAEouNXgKGiA8gCMAVlmC1+2WvLb4ACgCdKABywHahAHJgAtlghjx4oA)
- [без флага](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XTAcwKYC50DsBPJAXySWAHt8IAXdaAXmnywHc4LqJKQsA6EJQwAKMAEouNXgKGiA8gCMAVlmC1%202WvLb4ACgCdKABywHahAHJgAtlghjx4oA)
- [useDefineForClassFields + ESNext](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XTAcwKYC50DsBPJAXySWAHt8IAXdaAXmnywHc4LqJKQsA6EJQwAKMAEouNXgKGiA8gCMAVlmC1%202WvLb4ACgCdKABywHahAHJgAtlghjx4oA)

### Доки

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#useDefineForClassFields

> ## Использовать определение для полей класса - `useDefineForClassFields`
>
> Этот флаг используется как часть перехода на следующую стандартную версию полей класса. TypeScript представил поля классов за много лет до того, как он был ратифицирован в TC39. Последняя версия будущей спецификации отличается от реализации TypeScript во время выполнения, но с тем же синтаксисом.
>
> Этот флаг переключает на предстоящее поведение среды выполнения ECMA.
>
> Вы можете узнать больше о переходе [в примечаниях к выпуску 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier).